# C# Reading random frames from a video

Tags: library, video, c#

I need a C# library that allows to read video frames starting not from the beginning of a video.

For example, I want to get the 400-th frame. I'd like something that provides  a clear way to do this, like:

```
grabber.GetFrameByNumber(400);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you want to redistribute your program? If yes, with what license?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a commercial library to use for this, I recommend checking out the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia). The LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK is developed around the Microsoft DirectShow or Media Foundation libraries.

You can use the LEADTOOLS [PlayCtrl](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/multimedia/mm/leadtools.multimedia~leadtools.multimedia.playctrl_members.html) to load the video, navigate to the frame you wish to get the image from, then give you the image at that particular frame location. This can be done in just a few lines of code:

```
PlayCtrl playCtrl = new PlayCtrl();
playCtrl.SourceFile = @"Path the video file";
playCtrl.Run();
playCtrl.CurrentFramePosition += 399;
Image image = playCtrl.GetStillImage(0);
image.Save(@"Path to save image location", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Please note that I am an employee of this product.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Libvlc.Net](http://libvlcnet.sourceforge.net/)

Example code:

```
string filePath = GetTemporaryFilePath();
PlayerOutput output = new PlayerOutput();
output.Files.Add(new OutFile(filePath));
player = (Player)factory.CreatePlayer (output);
player.SetMediaInput(new MediaInput (MediaInputType.File, "/Users/rz/Movies/SampleMovie.mp4"));
player.Play();
```

You can implement your own `PlayerOutput` that just keeps the frame you want.

To save processing time you can make the player jump to a particular position before getting the frames. Be careful with time-to-frames conversion.

License: GNU GPL, same as the VLC player.